# How many SSL SKU I have to buy with 9 domains

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssl

I am new in this stuff releated with SSL and domains.

I am not sure how many SSL certificates I need to buy when I Have 9 domains (1 include in SAP and 8 additional bought)

I am almost sure they are 4 SSL certificates for each domain (1 for click, 1 for cloud, 1 for image and 1 for view)

Answer (score 2):

You need 4 SSL for every SAP domain (click,view,image,cloud)

You would need 1 SSL for every Private Domain used for cloudpages

a BU can only have 1 SAP domain, but a SAP domain can be shared with many BU

Comment: I understand. so is it not necessary buy 4 SSL for each extra domain? just 1 extra for each private domain? Can you explain me a little bit more?

thanks in advaced!!

Comment: SAP= bundle of products/features; Private Domain = one feature: https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/deliverability/private-domains-on-marketing-cloud-your-ultimate-guide/